# Need help creating a web spider/bot script in Perl

Tags: perl, scripting, web-crawler

I'm using Perl as the only language for this assignment

My Objective:

To create a Perl script that will create a web spider/bot. 
my script will download a webpage from the Internet, search and extract the Metatags, 
then index them in a MySQL database.

My database will then be searchable by the metatag fields or URL through a web interface.

My script will also display the full database including  a special field that lists the numbers of records in the database.

So my questions are:

How do I go about creating a script for a web spider that will download a webpage from the Internet and extract Metatags ?

What resources can i read up on to help me in creating this or any script for that matter?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Take a look at WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: If you are using Perl you might start out looking at the various HTTP modules in cpan: http://www.cpan.org/modules/index.html. (you can find WWW::Mechanize that Sebastian suggested there)

Comment: thanks for the advice. I had no idea about that website lol

Comment: You need to reduce the scope of this question. For example, the if it'd benefit a company isn't on-topic on SO. Your "what benefit" question probably isn't, either. Please try to keep questions focused on only one thing...

Comment: @derobert you're right I took out those fillers and kept it on topic.

Comment: what do you mean by "Metatags"?

Comment: WWW::Mechanize is probably overkill for the described use; LWP::UserAgent or even LWP::Simple would do

Comment: I love [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojocasts.com/e5) for simple tasks like that.

Comment: @ysth I was actually recommended by my prof to use these modules

CGI.pm
LWP
DBI.pm

LWP is on the list, but he gave me a list and that's it lol I didn't know what to do with these modules and what I mean by meta tags, something like 
' <META name="DC.identifier"
      content="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt"> '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prof. assumes that you would have some knowledge of Perl and also using CPAN modules. If you didn't know about CPAN, then start [here](http://www.perlhowto.com/what_is_cpan). Once you familiarize yourself with how to install and use modules from CPAN, install one of the modules guys suggested, and start writing code.

"How do I go about creating a script" is way too general. If you are new to Perl, then try [Impatient Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/impatient-perl/) or any other resource from [Perl.org](http://www.perl.org/) or various [tutorial sites](http://perl-tutorial.org).

Comment: thank you! I've been looking over the material and I'm kind of getting a hang of it now. The LWP::Simple is literally quite simple. Your answer basically solved my issue. Thanks